# Where is xxd in Windows gvim?

Tags: microsoft-windows, binary-file, xxd

Does it exist?  Is it Linux only?  Do I have to install it?

[According to this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Improved_hex_editing), it's `:!xxd` to convert the file to hex, and it's `:!xxd -r` to convert it back again.

Comment: `:!xxd` works for me on Windows. I've not installed anything special that I know of.

Answer (score 7):

It is distributed with Vim (as `xxd.exe`), along with `diff.exe`.

So it exists and should work on Windows. You don't need to install anything separately, as it is already bundled with Vim (at least in the versions available from vim.org).

Comment: Hey you're right, but it doesn't come up when I'm in there...maybe it's my home directory...or maybe I need to run it directly from that path.

Comment: Okay so I tried it like this `:!C:\Progra~2\vim\vim73\xxd.exe` and it just opens a window and sits there.

Comment: @leeand00 That is normal. It is waiting for an `EOF` character (Ctrl + c). Once you type that, it will stop running.

Comment: @leeand00 that is strange, it works without specifying the full path. You should try installing a newer version of Vim and/or start it without the .vimrc and any plugins (manually renaming them or with `vim -u NONE -U NONE -N -i NONE`).